# In Mocha, why do I want to use only()/skip()?

Tags: mocha.js

What is the point of [only() and skip()](https://mochajs.org/#exclusive-tests)? If I *only* want to have a single it/describe get executed, why should I keep the other things in the file? If I want to *skip* something, why shouldn't I just remove that code? When does one want to use those methods?

Answer (score 1):

About `only`. Imagine that you have 2000 unit tests in some `npm module`. And you need write 3 more tests for new feature. So you create `something.test.js` file and write test cases with `describe.only()`

```js
const assert = require('assert')

describe.only('sample class', () => {
    it('constructor works', () => {
        assert.deepEqual(true, true)
    })

    it('1st method works', () => {
        assert.deepEqual(true, true)
    })

    it('2nd method works', () => {
        assert.deepEqual(true, true)
    })
})
```

Now if you launch test locally via `npm test`, you run only your 3 tests, not whole bunch of 2003 tests. Tests are written much faster with `only`

About `skip`. Imagine that you need to implement urgent feature in 20mins, you don't have enough time to write tests, but you have time to document your code. As we know [unit tests are the best documentation](https://capgemini.github.io/development/unit-tests-as-documentation/), so you just write test cases how code should works with `describe.skip()`

```js
describe.skip('urgent feature', () => {
    it('should catch thrown error', () => {})
})
```

Now everyone in your team know about your new functionality and maybe someone write tests for you. Now the knowledge of how your new feature works is not only in your head, the whole team knows about it. It's good for the project and business.

[more reasons to use `skip`](https://blog.testproject.io/2019/03/05/7-reasons-to-skip-tests/)